# How to save the special characters into a MySQL database using a Java application?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, special-characters

I tried to save these special characters:

> © ™  ® ± ≠ ≤ ≥ ≅ ∞ µ α β Ω Σ Φ  φ   <> ° & %

into a MySQL databuse using a Java application, but its not working.

While implementing the JDBC driver into my application, I made sure to do it this way:

```
 jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncode=UTF-8
```

but it's still not working. Instead, most of the characters are just transformed into question marks (?) like shown in the screenshot below:

[My Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t12g6.png)

Comment: Does your db created with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes. But still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the URL to `jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

### Error:

Use `characterEncoding` instead of  `characterEncode`

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
String characters = "© ™ ® ± ≠ ≤ ≥ ≅  something";
String noCharacters = characters.trim();
```

Comment: Nope, thats not a problem. i fixed i wrongly passed url. `characterEncoding=UTF-8` is need to use but i used `characterEncode=UTF-8`